# Why can't I properly encode a boolean from PostgreSQL via JSON::XS via Perl?

Tags: perl, json, dbi

I have a query on a PostgreSQL system returning a boolean:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select 'f'::boolean");
$sth->execute;
my @vals = $sth->fetchrow_array;
```

According to [the DBD::Pg docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm),

> The current implementation of
>   PostgreSQL returns 't' for true and
>   'f' for false. From the Perl point of
>   view, this is a rather unfortunate
>   choice. DBD::Pg therefore translates
>   the result for the BOOL data type in a
>   Perlish manner: 'f' becomes the number
>   0 and 't' becomes the number 1. This
>   way the application does not have to
>   check the database-specific returned
>   values for the data-type BOOL because
>   Perl treats 0 as false and 1 as true.
>   You may set the pg_bool_tf attribute
>   to a true value to change the values
>   back to 't' and 'f' if you wish.

So, that statement should return a 0, which it does, so long as pg_bool_tf returns 0, which it does.  However, somewhere along the way JSON::XS (and plain JSON) interprets the returned 0 as a string:

```
use JSON::XS qw(encode_json);
my $options =
{
    layout => 0,
    show_widget_help => $vals[0] // 1,
};
die encode_json($options);
```

...dies with:

{"layout":0,"show_widget_help":"0"}

...which would be fine, except that my JavaScript is expecting a boolean there, and the non-empty string "0" gets evaluated to true.  Why is the latter 0 quoted and the former not?

According to [the JSON::XS docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON-XS/XS.pm), this is a main feature:

> round-trip integrity
>
> When you serialise a perl data
>   structure using only data types
>   supported by JSON, the deserialised
>   data structure is identical on the
>   Perl level. (e.g. the string "2.0"
>   doesn't suddenly become "2" just
>   because it looks like a number). There
>   minor are exceptions to this, read the
>   MAPPING section below to learn about
>   those.

...which says:

> Simple Perl scalars (any scalar that
>   is not a reference) are the most
>   difficult objects to encode: JSON::XS
>   will encode undefined scalars as JSON
>   null values, scalars that have last
>   been used in a string context before
>   encoding as JSON strings, and anything
>   else as number value.

But I never use @vals[0] in a string context.  Maybe DBD::Pg uses its boolean 0 as a string somewhere before returning it?

Comment: I found this thread too, and agree with the OP, you shouldn't need any "+0" hackery IMO: http://markmail.org/message/gecq4e24tx3doqkr#query:perl%20determining%20string%20or%20number+page:1+mid:wp34mllfgaax7pk2+state:results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `JSON::XS` doc says the following will be converted to `true`/`false`

- references to the integers `0` and `1`, ie. `\0` and `\1`
- `JSON::XS::true` and `JSON::XS::false`

Using one of these should solve your problem

Comment: It's true; however, these values are not what DBD::Pg returns.

Comment: Besides, that'd be the same amount of kludge as "::integer" or "+0".  To me, I think either JSON::XS or DBD::Pg are doing something wrong, but I don't know how to figure out which one, or whether that's actually true.

Comment: a peek at `DBD::Pg`'s `dequote_bool` suggests it may be returning the value as the strings "0" and "1", instead of an integer
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-2.13.1/quote.c

Comment: Ah, Dumper shows it as a string, and you're right about quote.c, I was wondering why I couldn't find anything in the actual .pm file.  I'll file a report with DBD::Pg.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Kev: If you want JSON::XS have true or false, using JSON::XS::true/false isn't a kludge, it's the right thing to do.

Comment: @ysth: Having to re-run through values that are already able to be marked as a specific type is kludge in my app, in my opinion.  I'm not saying it's kludge on the part of JSON::XS, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Update: Greg (the DBD::Pg maintainer) is looking into fixing it so it returns integers for integers and booleans, rather than strings for everything.

Comment: Update: the latest DBD::Pg fixes this.  Hooray!